# Runtime Ignoring While Loops?

Tags: java, netbeans, while-loop

I am new to the forums so first of all I'd like to say "Hi"! I'm new to Java programming and am trying to make a simple payroll calculating program with three while loops.

The first while loop keeps the program going until the user enters the sentinel "stop". The second and third loops are error traps that ensure the user enters a positive number before continuing.

For some reason, the while loops are not working and I have tried every variation I can think of. The program runs just fine, it just ignores the while loops. If someone could provide some suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong, I'd really appreciate it.

I'm using NetBeans 8.0 IDE if that helps.

Here is my code:

```
Import java.util.*;

Import java.text.*;

public class PayrollProgramVersion2 
{

    //begin main program
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        //declare new scanner
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in); // declare new scanner object
        DecimalFormat Dollars = new DecimalFormat ("$0.00"); //format for dollars
        String Employee; //employee's name
        Double Hours, //hours worked
        Rate, //pay rate
        Pay; // Hours * Rate
        Boolean Continue = true; // sentinel for program loop
        //welcome user, prompt for employee name, and assign input to Employee
        System.out.println ("Welcome to the payroll program!");
        System.out.println ("What is the employee's name? (Enter stop to quit.)");
        Employee = sc.nextLine();
        // while loop continues program until user enters "stop"
        while (Continue == true) 
        {
            if (Employee.equalsIgnoreCase("stop"))
            {
                Continue = false;
            } // end if
            else
            {
                //prompt for hours worked and assign to Hours
                System.out.println ("How many hours did " +Employee+ " work?");
                Hours = sc.nextDouble();
                //this block is an error trap to ensure input is positive before continuing
                while (Hours < 0)
                {
                    System.out.println( "Error - input must be a positive number");
                    System.out.println ("How many hours did " +Employee+ " work?");
                    Hours = sc.nextDouble();
                }
                //prompt for pay rate and assign to Rate
                System.out.println( "How much does " +Employee+ " make per hour?");
                Rate = sc.nextDouble();
                //this block is an error trap to ensure input is positive before continuing
                while (Rate < 0)
                {
                    System.out.println( "Error - input must be a positive number"); 
                    System.out.println( "How much does " +Employee+ " make per hour?");
                    Rate = sc.nextDouble();
                }
                Pay = Hours * Rate; // calculate payrate
                //display results
                System.out.println(Employee+ "'s paycheck is " +(Dollars.format(Pay))+ ".");
                System.out.println ("What is the employee's name? (Enter stop to quit.)");
                Employee = sc.nextLine();
            } //end else
        } //end while
        System.out.println ("Thank you for using the payroll program. Goodbye!");
    } // end main

} // end program
```

Comment: what do you mean "it ignores the while loops" ?
have you tried debugging and checking the values on which is tested?

Comment: Please follow *Java Naming Conventions* and name your variables accordingly. Also please write `if(someVariable)` to check if it's `true`.

Comment: What are with your capitals? `Import`, `Boolean` and `Double` should be `import`, `boolean` and `double`. The first one is an error; the second and third do something but not the same thing.

Comment: Make sure to close your scanner at the end of the program

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see you should make your `while (hours<0)` to `while (hours<0 || hours == null)`.

This is because... As far as I can see you initialise hours. But no value is input into it. So it remains as `null`. You could also try changing the while to an if.

Hope this helps. It may be that it does default to 0 but it may be worth for testin purposes to have a console output.

```
System.out.println(hours);
```

Befor the while loop to see what your program is reading `hours` as.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The line: `Hours = sc.nextDouble();` pretty much assigns a value to `Hours`.

Answer (score 0):

When you do something like:

```
Hours = sc.nextDouble();
```

you trust the user to enter a `double` value, and in case the user entered illegal value, a `String` for example, this line will throw an exception.

You can solve it like this:

```
while (Hours < 0)
{
    System.out.println( "Error - input must be a positive number");
    System.out.println ("How many hours did " +Employee+ " work?");
    String hours = sc.nextLine();
    try {
        Hours = Double.valueOf(hours);
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // keep looping until we get a legal value
        Hours = -1.0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The *error* is that `nextDouble` does not eat the newline. It skips newlines at the beginning, so in effect only the last nextDouble is concerned.

Best to make a utility function:

Instead of

```
Hours = sc.nextDouble();
```

call your own function:

```
Hours = nextDouble(sc);

private static double nextDouble(Scanner sc) {
    double value = -1.0;
    if (sc.hasNextDouble()) {
        value = sc.nextDouble();
    }
    sc.nextLine();
    return value;
}
```

---

Use a small initial letter for field and method names.
Use double/boolean/int instead of the Double/Boolean/Integer as the latter are Object wrappers (classes); the first primitive types.

Call `sc.close();` (for good order).

Answer (score 0):

Aside from what has been said above:

`sc.nextDouble` consumes and returns the next input from the current line. It does not forward the line.
  `sc.nextLine` consumes and returns the input from the current line and forwards to the next line

At the end of your while loop you call `Employee = sc.nextLine();` If you follow your logic and only input allowed values, this will always return an empty string as it consumes the current line where your most previously removed double was stored(now empty string "")